# Microsoft Dynamics AX filtering data based on a ComboBox

Tags: combobox, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, morph-x

I got a functionality to implement:

In PurchTable form in am told to create a combox on top of form which used enum as in purchTable.purchstatus field ie:invoiced,openorder,reveived,.

Now on clicking on any one of the above element in combo box i should only get that data in the grid below ie;if i click on invoiced ,record with purch status 'invoiced' will be show.

for this i created a combobox and used overidden method "selectionchange"
code of selectionchange():

```
public int selectionChange()
{
    int ret;

 ret = super();
if(combobox.selection()==status::invoiced)
   {
  ... what will i have to write here to add range"invoiced" in the datasource 

  }



   if(combobox.selection()==status::All)
  {
 .  .. what will i have to write here to add range"invoiced" in the datasource 

 }

  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use this code (tested in AX2009) for your selectionChange() handler.
Note: On your ComboBox you should set the property `EnumType` to `PurchStatus` (see Screenshot) so that the enum's elements are automatically added as entries.

If you have any questions regarding this code don't hesitate to comment ...

```
public int selectionChange()
{
    int             ret;
    QueryBuildRange range;
    ;

    ret = super();
    range = SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(
        purchTable_DS.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(PurchTable)),
        fieldnum(PurchTable, PurchStatus));
    range.value(queryValue(this.selection()));
    purchTable_DS.executeQuery();

    return ret;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a Form with a DataSource called `JAEEMantenimiento` that you want to filter from the field `Tipo`, and a data-unbound combobox called `FiltroTipo`. This is the code you need to filter when combo changes selection:

```
// classDeclaration of the FORMULARIO!!
public class FormRun extends ObjectRun
{
    QueryBuildRange     qbrTipo;
}

// Form DATASOURCE (JAEEMantenimiento)
public void init()
{
    super();

    qbrTipo = JAEEMantenimiento_DS.queryBuildDataSource()
                    .addRange(fieldNum(JAEEMantenimiento, Tipo));
}

// Form DATASOURCE (JAEEMantenimiento)
public void executeQuery()
{
    qbrTipo.value(queryValue(FiltroTipo.selection()));

    super();
}

// COMBOBOX (FiltroTipo)
public boolean modified()
{
    boolean ret;

    ret = super();

    JAEEMantenimiento_DS.executeQuery();

    return ret;
}
```

This is AX 2012 code, but it should work just fine in 2009.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but I am not getting .querybuilddatasource method in drp down in init() method.public void init()
{
    super();

    qbrTipo = JAEEMantenimiento_DS.queryBuildDataSource()
                    .addRange(fieldNum(JAEEMantenimiento, Tipo));
}